# Protractor: executing command on remote machine

Tags: protractor

How we can execute a command or Node script on a remote machine from Protractor test case file ?

Comment: rewrite as a question

Answer (score 0):

Have used child_process lib of node for executing jar file. 
My requirement was to execute existing JAR file from test case inside the protractor framework and reading the std output.

Have used below code snippet

```
const exec= require('child_process').exec;
const subprocess = exec("java -jar xxxxxx.jar argument", function(err, stdout, stderr){
         if(err){
                console.log(err)
         }
         console.log(stdout);
});
```

Hope this solution will help others.